# Does django have something similar to resource in rails?

Tags: python, django

I just started learning django. I was a rails developer before that. I was wondering if there is anything similar to resource in rails in django? Or do I have to make different urls and corresponding views for those urls? Thanks in advance!

Comment: my bad. I meant resources. It allows you to do CRUD operations

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Rails has a [concept of resources](http://www.stephenchu.com/2007/11/seeing-rails-resources-clearly.html) for CRUD operations

Comment: Sounds like [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

Comment: @karthikr thanks for the link. Is there something similar in django?

Comment: @gabby no, there isn't - Not anything that's generated for you. But you have the concepts of Classbased views which Ignacio was talking about. This is okay though, since you're not using rails magics to get stuff done. :)

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but this might be helpful as a Rails dev learning Django: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2456-railsconf2013-sleeping-with-the-enemy #shamelessselfpromotion

Answer (score 0):

[django-smarter](https://github.com/05bit/django-smarter) provides a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about RESTful APIs to the django models if I understand correctly.  Django does not do it for you natively (as jpic said) but there are some packages you can install to do that:

- django-smarter (as jpic said)
- tastypie
- django rest framework

See https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/rest/ for a list of APIs that can be added in to django.  I see django-smarter isn't on that list.  Maybe someone should add it.